# (React RTK) How to properly assign a custom selectId in createEntityAdapter

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, entity

My data structure is not strictly an array, it is more like an array inside of a nested object.

```
{
    "start": "3-1-2021",
    "event_log": [
        {
            "event_id": 1,
            "rul": 61300,
            "start": "3-1-2021"
        },
        {
            "event_id": 2,
            "rul": 61299,
            "start": "3-1-2021"
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I extract the `event_id` as the entity and pass it into the `createEntityAdapter`. I have tried this:

```
const chartAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
    selectId: (data) => data.event_log.map(item => item.event_id)
});
```

But it is not working. Anyone has an idea of how to ignore the `start` and destructure the `event_id` from `event_log` and pass it into the `createEntityAdapter`. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
const EventLogAdapter = createEntityAdapter<EventLog>({
  selectId: log => log.event_id,
})

type State = Partial<{
  start: string
  // other fields
}> & {
  eventLogs: EntityState<EventLogAdapter>
}

const initialState: State = {
  eventLogs: EventLogAdapter.getInitialState(),
}

const LogsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'logs',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // reducers
  },
})
```

Similar answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58729161/13398368)